# SSRS expressions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I need to implement the following expression in a tablix:

1.`NewRetail < cost then " NR is below cost"`

2.`% Change >=20% then " NR is >=20%"`

Here **% change** is a derived column.

I tried:

```
=Switch(Fields!NEW_RETAIL.Value < Fields!PC.Value, "New Retail is below cost", ReportItems!Change.Value >= 20%, "New retail is >=20%")
```

and:

```
=IIF(Fields!NEW_RETAIL.Value < Fields!PC.Value, "New Retail is below cost", IIF(ReportItems!Change.Value >= 20%, "New retail is >=20%")," ")
```

But both do not work!

Comment: Check you are comparing with the 20% is the derived column contain the % in it and the closing bracket of the second IIF statement is wrong check it. Current I am leaving so I am in hurry. There will be no reply further until monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"20%" is string, and the expression "> 20%" does not really have meaning (Even if it did, 20% of what?)

Try

```
 =IIF(
   Fields!NEW_RETAIL.Value < Fields!PC.Value, "New Retail is below cost",
  IIF(ReportItems!Change.Value >= 20, "New retail is >=20%"," "))
```

Check to see that ReportItems!Change.Value has a number in it, as well. (It might be formatted as a percent with a textbox format, but the value should still be a number, not a string with "%" at the end.